# Finite subset of projective $n$ space is a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

> How do I prove that a finite subset $M$ of the $n$-dimensional projective space is a variety?

I tried finding a homogeneous polynomial of degree one that vanishes at an arbitrary x in M and then go from there, but to no avail.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is easy to come up with an ideal that vanishes at exactly a single point of affine $n$-space: for the point $\mathbf{p}=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$, the ideal $I=(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ vanishes at $\mathbf{p}$ and only $\mathbf{p}$. That means that the homogeneous ideal $(x_1-a_1x_0,x_2-a_2x_0,\ldots,x_n-a_nx_0)$ of $K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ vanishes exactly at the projective point $(1:a_1\colon a_2\colon\cdots \colon a_n)$ of projective $n$-space.

So a single point (whether projective or affine) is an algebraic set. The union of two algebraic sets is algebraic, since if $Y_1$ is the zero set of $I$ and $Y_2$ is the zero set of $J$, then $Y_1\cup Y_2$ is the zero set of $IJ$. Inductively, the union of any finite collection of algebraic sets is algebraic. In particular, any finite subset of $n$-dimensional (projective or affine) space is algebraic.

A single point is thus an algebraic variety (in the sense given by Hartshorne, which requires it to be an irreducible algebraic set). But a finite collection of points that has more than one point is not irreducible.

If your definition of variety requires irreducibility, then $M$ is not a variety unless $M$ is a singleton or empty. If it does not require irreducibility, then the above works.

Comment: Thanks! I just started learning AG today so some terms are unfamiliar to me, but I think I got it.

Comment: You said a single point in projective space is algebraic. What about a point at infinity? For instance, $(0:a:b)$ is the variety determined by the forms $aY-bX$ and $Z$?

Comment: @HritRoy: the point $[0:a:b]$ is the zero set of $(X,bY-aZ)$. You can also see this by noting that projective space is covered by affine pieces, and you can realize the single point in the corresponding affine space (in this case, $X=0$), and then projectivize by homogenizing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm not sure I understand the process. The point would have been $V(Y-a,Z-b)$ in the space $X=0$. Now how am I arriving at $bY-aZ$? In my previous comment I just happened to see what it would be without following any method.

Comment: @HritRoy:In projective space, it should be a homogeneous ideal, so every generator should be homogeneous. You don’t start with $(y-a,z-b)$. If $a\neq 0$, then the point is $[0:1:b’]$, and you look in the affine space $Y\neq 0$; you get $(x/y,z/y -b’)$. Then you homogeneize to get $(X,Z-b’Y)$. Since $b’=b/a$, this is the same as $(X,aZ-bY)$, or $(X,bY-aZ)$. (cont)

Comment: @HritRoy: If $a=0$, then the point is $[0:0:1]$, and in the space $Z\neq 0$, you have $(x,y)$. This coresponds to $(x/z,y/z)$, so homogenizing you get $(X,Y)$. Which, in this case, is the same as $(X,bY-aZ)$ since $a=0$ and $(X,bY)=(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 4):

It suffices to show that a point is a variety. Call that point $x$. Take any other point $y$. $x = [x_0, \cdots, x_n]$ being different from $y = [y_0, \cdots, y_n]$ means that some ratio $x_i/x_j \neq y_i/y_j$. Take the linear form $x_jz_i - x_i z_j$. This vanishes on $x$ not $y$. Now vary $y$ (and the corresponding $i,j$), and put all such linear forms together.

Comment: Dear Soarer, the equations $x_jz_i - x_i z_j=0$ you write are correct but have  nothing to do with $y$ and they shouldn't. What you have to vary is the pair i,j and not an irrelevant $y$. For example three (redundant)  equations define $(a_0:a_1:a_2)\in \mathbb P^2$. One of them is $a_0z_1-a_1z_0=0$.

Comment: Dear Georges, I meant to say vary $y$ and the pair $i,j$. The answer is now edited. (Edit: Now I see what you are saying. When I was writing the answer I was having in mind to have one linear form separating $x$ and each point different from $x$, but of course, although to each $y$ corresponds to at least one linear form, these linear forms put together are really just dependent on $x$)

Comment: Dear Soarer, consider the point (4:2:3). My point of view yields the (redundant) three equations $2z_0-4z_1=0,\quad 3z_0-4z_2=0$ and $\; 3z_1-2z_2=0$. What equations do you get by your procedure?

Comment: Dear Georges, what we do are essentially the same I think, though the way I thought about it when writing the answer was more convoluted.

Comment: Take your example. (4:2:3). Take $(a,b,c) \neq (4,2,3)$. If $a:b \neq 2:1$, we have an equation $x - 2y = 0$. If $b:c \neq 2:3$ we have an equation $3y - 2z = 0$, if $a:c \neq 4:3$, we have an equation $3x - 4z = 0$. So the point would be defined as the zero set of $x - 2y = 0 $, $3y-2z = 0$ and $3x - 4z = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, Soarer. I am happy that we are in complete agreement.